# Vue Firebase - convert array of firestore timestamp value to readable javascript date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Im able to get document data from firestore collection as array and put them on view but dont know how to convert the timestamp value to readable date.

[image]

```
getDocs(collection(db, "timeoffreq"))
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    const array = []
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      array.push(doc.data())
    });
    timeoffreq.value = array
})
  
const timeoffreq = ref([{}])
```

And I just put it to view like this:

```
<tr v-for="(timeoffreq, timeoffreqIdx) in timeoffreq" :key="timeoffreq.uid" :class="timeoffreqIdx % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-gray-50'">
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
        {{ timeoffreq.type }}
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
        {{ timeoffreq.desc }}
      </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
        {{ timeoffreq.start }}
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
        {{ timeoffreq.end }}
     </td>
     <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
     <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

But the start and end field output show up like this:

```
Timestamp(seconds=1663174800, nanoseconds=0)
```

how do i convert `start` and `end` fields to readable date first?

I tried something like this:

```
var date = new Date(timeoffreq.start).toDateString()
console.log(date)
```

but the output: `Invalid Date`

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from the Firebase console of a document in the `timeoffreq` collection?

Comment: Don't you need a `v-repeat` to handle the array?
https://012.vuejs.org/guide/list.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edit the question. pls check it again. thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Did you also see my comment about using `v-repeat` to handle the fact that your `timeoffreq` is an array?

Comment: But im using v-for already. Is it a must to using v-repeat? im still new to Vue but v-repeat is deprecated or for older version I think. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Timestamp class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) to convert date field to `Date` object.

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app"
const date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp(timeoffreq.start).toDate()
```

Or just simply use the `seconds` field to convert

```js
const date = new Date(timeoffreq.start.seconds)
```

Comment: the second one give error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds')`